# Difference between adb shell [command] and interactive adb shell

Tags: adb, mksh

I am wondering if the interactive shell `adb shell` runs in a different context then when invoking a command via `adb shell [command]`?

The background to this question is, that I am running `dinit` on an Android powered board. `dinit` is started in user mode just for service management. When I run `dinitctl -u list` from the interactive shell I get the expected output (enabled services and their current state), but when I run it via `adb shell dinitctl -u list` I just get an error about the socket not being found (as if `dinit` itself was not running).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that running `adb shell [command]` does not source `/etc/mkshrc`. Setting the required env variables before the command solves my issue.